# How to mimic a Promise in Python?

Tags: python, express, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have set up an endpoint in Express.js that can start a long "for" loop and return a response before the loop finishes (thanks to Promises which push - I believe - the function to message queue):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const long_task = () => {
    for (let i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        return new Promise(r => r(console.log(i)))
    }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    long_task()
    res.send('endpoint returned')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

(for now it does not matter that the server will not be able to process any other requests before the loop finishes).

Now, I want to mimic this in a Python framework, preferably FastAPI, due to its async capabilities.

So far I have this:

```
async def async_print(value):
    print(value)

async def long_task():
    for i in range(10000):
        await async_print(i)

@app.get('/')
async def testing_long_task():
    await long_task()
    return 'endpoint returned'
```

But, as expected, the code will pause at `await long_task()`, and only return a response once the loop is finished.
And if I replace `await long_task()` with just `long_task()` I will get an error that the coroutine `long_task` was never awaited.

Is there any way to achieve such async for loop in FastAPI without using its background tasks or task queue like Celery?

Comment: The closest equivalent of JS's unawaited `long_task()` would be `asyncio.create_task(long_task())`. I'm not 100% sure what `await new Promise(...)` is doing in JS, but you might want to try `await asyncio.create_task(async_print(i))` or perhaps `await async_print(i); await asyncio.sleep(0)`. (Both will force a context switch, if that's the point of the original. The former is closer to the original code, the latter is more efficient, though still inadvisable.) It's hard to tell whether there's a better way to do things because it's not clear what kind of long task you're dealing with.

Comment: Why don't you like to use FastAPIs background tasks?

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/

Comment: Coroutines that are not awaited are garbage collected and won't be executed. Just put it in a background task, where you can do as much other things as you want, while your coroutine is running in the background (for example using asyncio.gather()).

You can then safely return a 201 accepted and the behaviour will be the same as your unawaited JS promise.